# How to change dtype of columns inside list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, dtype

I'm trying to make a calculation where I have columns with different dtypes, as this gives a mistake I want to have all of them the same dtype.

```
Question            object
Very likely         object
Quite likely       float64
Slightly likely     object
Not very likely    float64
Very unlikely       object
Total              float64
dtype: object
```

I've tried to use float(x) in lambda function.

```
propensity = pd.read_excel(raw_data,'Propensity to buy')
propensity = propensity[['Question','Very likely','Quite likely','Slightly likely','Not very likely',
                          'Very unlikely','Total']]

propensity['MEAN'] = 
sum(
    [
        propensity['Very likely'].apply(lambda float(x): x*4),

        propensity['Quite likely'].apply(lambda float(x): x*3),

        propensity['Slightly likely'].apply(lambda float(x): x*2),

        propensity['Not very likely'].apply(lambda float(x): x*1),

        propensity['Very unlikely'].apply(lambda float(x): x*0)
    ]
)
```

The result obtained is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `lambda <argument_names>: <do_work>` Your syntax doesn't make sense because you're trying to "do work" on the "wrong side". Having said that, you should be exploring how to change type of a pandas column, you don't need to use `.apply`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `df['column_name'].astype(int)`? You can create a for loop if you wish to evaluate certain columns:

```
cols = ['column_1','column_2','column_3','column_n']
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('int')
```

or an use dtype as a condition:

```
if df['column_1'].dtype == object:
    print("this column contains is dtype object")
else:
    print("it is dtype is not object")
```

Once you have them as int or float, you can perform your regular calculations.

Comment: Hello, as I understand, for cols = ['column_1','column_2','column_3','column_n']
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('int') 

I just need to change df for my dataframe name and leave col as it is right? I ask because it's what I'm doing and I'm receiving an error 'invalid literal for int() with base 10:'

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: float(x) * 4)
```

instead of

```
df['column_name'].apply(lambda float(x): x*4)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by casting the columns when your reading the data from source: 
eg:

```
pd.read_excel('file_name', dtype={'Very likely': 'float64', 'Quite likely': 'float64', 'Slightly likely': 'float64', 'Not very likely': 'float64', 'Very unlikely': 'float64'})
```

Comment: Hello, after trying your solution I got this error:

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Comment: See this Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html